# Fast algorithm for generating consecutive primes larger than N

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, sieve-theory

I'm looking for a fast algorithm to generate primes larger than a random 4096 bit number $N$. I know about the *Sieve of Atkin*, but AFAIK it can only be used to find all primes up to a certain limit. At the moment I am using a combination of sieving out composites of small primes plus *Miller-Rabin-Test*. Probabilistic methods are OK - I just need to generate good candidates quickly...

Comment: How many primes greater than $N$ you are trying to find? It seems rather unbounded :/

Comment: Well, I'm actually looking for primes $p$, such that $q=2p+1$ and $r=2q+1$ are also prime. And these are quite rare, so I want to generate as many as possible primes in a fixed amount of time. But if you want a bound, let's just say: I need to generate a million primes as fast as possible.

Comment: So examples would be and $2,5,11$, $5,11,23$, and $11,23,47$?

Comment: Yes, exactly...